# Do I need to sand my pressure-treated deck before staining?

Tags: wood

I just got a new deck built using pre-treated wood. Do I need to sand it down before staining? I was told it was already sanded since it was pre-treated and it looks smooth and feels smooth so I don't think it needs sanding, but I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119757/do-i-need-to-sand-my-new-deck-before-staining-it

Answer (score 0):

All typical lumber is S4S (sanded on four sides). Really, this means that it was *milled* on four sides, but it's usually quite smooth. That said, I usually hit railings and other commonly touched areas with a random orbit before finishing.

The bigger question is how long to wait. Pressure-treated lumber is extremely wet and must be allowed to dry to some degree. Follow your product's recommendations.